# How do I stop div and table elements from overlapping the header/footer?

Tags: html

I have a problem I haven't found an answer to in similar questions:

I have a site that dynamically resizes a horizontal scrolling image gallery and some text as you resize the browser. That part I have working OK, I just can't seem to get proper control of each respective element.

Take a look: http://john-godwin.co.uk/testsite

If you resize the browser, the large text overlaps the gallery before the gallery starts shrinking, and if you resize the browser small enough, the gallery eventually overlaps the footer as well.

Does anyone know what changes I need to make to the code to make everything stay within a boundary and resize respective of the other elements without encroaching into each elements space?

Thanks in advance.

The CSS can be found in http://john-godwin.co.uk/testsite/css/style.css

Answer (score 1):

Remove `z-index:500;` in the .content class

Comment: that should fix the problem you have with the gallery overlapping your footer, when you say the large text overlaps the gallery before the gallery starts shrinking, do you mean the "John Goodwin Photography"?

Comment: Yes, indeed, sorry, I haven't explained enough. The z-index is just to put the gallery over everything except the login drop-down, it hasn't changed or responsible for the behaviour I describe. What I mean is that when you shrink the browser, ALL of the elements overlap each other. I want it to they only resize smoothly without overlapping. So yes, when you shrink the browser, I want the text to shrink like it does, but I want the gallery element to respect the boundaries and shrink accordingly so that nothing gets lost under each other.